# Rewind animation on exit slide powerpoint

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a powerpoint with several slides linked together with hyperlinks. Each slide has an animation timeline. The animations play, but when I use the hyperlinks to go back to a slide where the animations have already played, they do not play!

How do I get it so that when I click back to a slide where the aniamtions have already played, the animations will play again?

I am using Powerpoint 2010.

Comment: - @ Please show the link you are using

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is a link to another slide in the same powerpoint.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have a test case powerpoint, how can I give it to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations in PowerPoint only play when you go to the slide from the previous slide. For example, if your animations are on slide 12, they will only play when you go to slide 12 from slide 11.

To make them play when you're going to slide 12 from another slide, insert a new slide just before slide 12; it can be a plain black or white slide or a duplicate of slide 12 with the animated shapes deleted.

Give this new slide 11 an automatic transition to the next slide after 0 seconds, duration 0 seconds.

Now hyperlink to slide 11 instead of to slide 12.  The transition will happen so quickly that it will be invisible; nobody will ever see slide 11 but when slide 12 appears, the animations will play again.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for the solution! I no longer use MS office or Windows, but I'm sure your answer will be useful to future visitors that find this answer through a search engine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Rewind ?

This is an image of my 2011 PowerPoint, to see the [2010 go here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/powerpoint-help/set-the-animation-timing-or-effect-options-HA101792360.aspx).

[image]

To go back,I use the Action button.

Comment: If you mean converting all my hyperlinks into actions (insert -> action), that did not work. As for the rewind, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I did not mean all of them, just the last one to have the return to beginning action button.

Comment: As for the rewind ! does our version of PP (mine is 2011 but that should not matter) has that check mark in the Timing Rewind settings for the animation ? If checked that will rewind the animation, and play it again when selected.

Comment: I have added the link for you in my answer. It explains how to use the rewind on 2010.

Comment: The rewind when done playing makes the animation play every time I go to the slide, but then the object disappears.

Comment: That will depend on what did you use as animation start. Now you got the animation to rewind and that was your question or not?